# Append in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have a file test.txt which has a line like below

```
values =  abc, def, dfg, ert, sdf, sfd, sdf
```

I use the shell script to add a new value with comma separation in the values in the test,txt.

For example, I need to **add** the 'ghf' in the test.txt:

```
values =  abc, def, dfg, ert, sdf, sfd, sdf, ghf
```

Also I need to remove the value.

For example, if I need to **remove** the 'ert' in the test.txt:

```
values =  abc, def, dfg, sdf, sfd, sdf, ghf
```

How can I achieve this in shell script?

**(i.e)**

If I give the

```
echo "abc" >> test.txt
```

It is able to append the "abc" to the end of the file
but I need to append to the 'values=' field in test.txt

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Use `sed` which is the right tool for your requirements

Comment: Use `ed` which might be a better tool for your requirement

Comment: Are these ert and ghf values one-time (static) changes, or does the script need to prompt for add/remove and the value?

Comment: How do you know when you want to remove `ert`?  I don't see an example of how you'd expect to do that.

Comment: [Cross-post of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50238794/append-to-line-with-a-specific-key-in-shell)

Answer (score 1):

Fast solution without a guard from corner cases.
(Thanks [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) for `sed` optimizations.)

## Adding

`sed -i "/^values = / s/$/, ${NEW_VALUE}/" test.txt`

#### Explanation

`sed -i` - Make changes in the given file, do not print to the `stdout`.

`/^values = /` - When `sed` is positioned on the line that starts with `values =`.

`s/$/, ${NEW_VALUE}/` - Append `, ${NEW_VALUE}` at the end of the line.

`test.txt` - File on which `sed` will perform actions.

## Removing

`sed -i "/^values = / s/ ${REMOVE_VALUE},\?//" test.txt`

#### Explanation

`s/ ${REMOVE_VALUE},\?//` - Remove the first occurence of `${REMOVE_VALUE}` along with optional following `,`.

## Problems with this solution

1. Adding the first value will add `,` right after `values =`
2. Removing the last value will leave the line ending with `,`.
3. If added/removed variables containt `sed`'s separator for `s` command (in my example it is `/`), command won't work.

Comment: good suggestion. However you are making sed do too much work: there's no need to match everything only to put it into the replacement. Just match the end-of-line and add the new value there. Also, you need double quotes for the shell to expand the variable: `sed -i "/^values = / s/$/$NEW_VALUE/" file`

Comment: Same with the next one: `sed -ir "/^values = / s/ $REMOVE_VALUE,//" file`

Comment: In general, you don't need `.*` at the beginning or end of the pattern if you're going to just put them into the replacement unchanged.

Comment: @glennjackman Wow, very good observation! Thank you very much, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed` you can do the following:

```
ed -s test.txt <<<$'/values/s/$/,ghf\nw'   # add ghf to the end of line
```

and

```
ed -s values <<<$'/values/s/ert,//\nw'  # remove ert
```